# How does String.fromCharCode(n) deal with special character codes like 'NUL'?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `String.fromCharCode(n)` (where n is a number), to return a string representation of number values, ranging from 0 to 127 (the ASCII character set). What happens when I pass in values that don't directly correlate to a printable character, like 0 (which is NUL in ASCII)?

I tested it by using an alert which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2QNW/), although in that case I think some type coercion is taking place.

Comment: I'm not saying your question is bad but I don't see what you really ask. What's not clear [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) ?

Comment: Be careful with the `alert` : as it's natively handled by the browsers, it doesn't always correctly handle the null character (see [this issue I entered](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164126)).

Answer (score 5):

You get a string containing that character. It will print as an empty string because the character has no printable representation, but the string will contain the character. For example:

```
String.fromCharCode(0) === "\u0000" // true
String.fromCharCode(0, 1) === "\u0000\u0001" // also true
```

Note that you can get a NULL embedded into your string this way; it's not like C where the NULL character is assumed to be the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.fromCharCode(10) ="\n"
```

For NULL it will show like this in Firebug. In document it is not displayable (since it is null)

```
String.fromCharCode(0) = "" 
(will show empty string, since this is marked as non-displayable string character)
```

In firebug sometimes it shows as "�", but once refreshing it will show empty string.

Comment: You comment is wrong. \0 isn't a string termination character in JS.